# How to save data in SQL and loop on it?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus

once i run first query i got the below result:

```
REQUEST_NO R
---------- -
   4309300 A
   4300983 C
```

and i want to compare if R column is different to "C" run second query and do the same for each element that i can have in REQUEST_NO column different to C

```
SELECT REQUEST_NO
       , REQUEST_STS 
FROM  PORT_REQUEST 
WHERE REQUEST_NO IN (SELECT DISTINCT REQUEST_NO 
                     FROM SUB_PORT_REQUEST 
                     WHERE SUBSCRIBER_NO = replace(replace('&CTN','-',''),' ',''));

Enter value for ctn: 5161890110

REQUEST_NO R
---------- -
   4309300 A
   4300983 C


SELECT ACT_SEQ_NO 
FROM SUB_PORT_REQUEST 
WHERE REQUEST_NO=&Req_No 
AND ROWNUM <=1 
ORDER BY ACT_SEQ_NO DESC;

Enter value for req_no: 4309300

ACT_SEQ_NO
----------
  91180671
```

I expect to save in a array or something all values and can be able to iterate on it, can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

One option, if you want to remain in SQL*Plus, is to create a (global temporary?) table, store result of the first query into it, and then rewrite the second query to use those results as

```
where request_no in (select request_no from my_temporary_table)
```

---

Another is to switch to PL/SQL and write a procedure which will accept CTN as a parameter. It (PL/SQL) allows you to use different ways to store results of the first query - into a table (as previously) or an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine these to just 1 query by joining the tables. I am  not sure I know how to handle the segment "and rownum<=1 Order by ...". Either the order by clause is not needed as rownum<=1 will produce at most 1 row and no matter how you sort it 1 row always comes out the same. Or you expect multiple rows want only want the greatest act_seq_no. If that is the case you need the order by in a sub-query and the rownum predicate on the outer. Assuming the latter we get:
Also assuming the column you refer to as R in description is actually the column port_request.request_sts as R is NOT selected nor is it an alias for any referenced column given.

```
select act_seq_no
  from ( select spr.act_seq_no 
           from sub_port_request spr
           join port_request     pr
             on (spr.request_no = pr.request_no and
                 pr.request_sts != 'C'
                )
          where spr.subscriber_no = replace(replace('&CTN','-',''),' ','')
          order by spr.act_seq_no desc
       )
 where rownum<=1;
```